# Is there any function in Unity 2d , when I die the the game over screen comes only after death animation finishes

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Any way to show Game over screen only after the death animation of player is played text**

Answer (score 0):

Check in update if animation is playing or not. if animaion.IsPlaying() return false means your animation is finish and then you show your game over screen.

Answer (score 0):

in your player script (or whatever script tells your die animation to play), go below the line where the die animation plays, then write this line of code: `StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());`. Make sure you replace the 'ExampleCoroutine' part with the name of the IEnumerator method (more on that in the next sentence). Next, go below the function where you typed `StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());`. and make an `IEnumerator` method. Inside it type `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);`. and replace the 1 with how long it takes for the die animation to finish. Lastly, below that line, activate your game over screen. Hope this helped a bit!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach code functions to animations, you can use [animation events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) to call functions at very specific times during (or at the end of) animations.

If you prefer, you can also use events to transmit animation status from inside your animator controller using [state machine behaviours](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBehaviours.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable playeranimationfinised and use an IEnumerator with WaitUntil like this

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public IEnumerator gameover()
{
    //function to check animation finished
    Func<bool> animationfinished = () => playeranimationover;
    //wait until playeranimationover is true
    yield return new WaitUntil(animationfinished);
    //show gameoverscreen
}
```